# how to remove slowness from loading document library message in Alfresco 6.0?

Tags: alfresco, alfresco-share

i have an issue with my alfresco repository it takes a long time to enter folders; i'm usign alfresco 6 deployed via docker-compose, with mysql 5.7 instaled in host server
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3ZNe2.png)

Answer (score 0):

Did you try optimizing the databases, you can run below command in your mysql server

```
mysqlcheck –auto-repair –check –optimize –all-databases
```